# In MySql, SELECT all with DIFFERENT id?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I Have a Table like,

*(Please note, this question might sound like **duplicate** but I checked other questions before posting this... If you find the answer in other posts, **Advice** me rather than **downvoting**. I promise to delete it just incase. thx)*

```
|tid |name|age|sex|pack_id
 1   |Joe |57 |M  |77
 2   |Joe |57 |M  |77
 3   |Joe |57 |M  |89
 4   |Joe |57 |M  |89
 5   |Joe |57 |M  |94

 6   |Roy |98 |M  |7
 7   |Roy |98 |M  |8
 8   |Roy |98 |M  |9
 9   |Roy |98 |M  |7
 10  |Roy |98 |M  |7
 11  |Roy |98 |M  |7

 12  |Joe |46 |M  |96

 13  |Guh |97 |F  |1

 14  |Kin |68 |F  |33
 15  |Kin |68 |F  |37
 16  |Kin |68 |F  |37
 17  |Kin |68 |F  |37
 18  |Kin |68 |F  |35
 19  |Kin |68 |F  |37

 20  |Pit |43 |F  |77
 21  |Pit |43 |F  |1
 22  |Pit |43 |F  |2
 23  |Pit |43 |F  |1
 24  |Pit |43 |F  |77

 25  |Joe |71 |M  |75

 26  |Bob |82 |M  |77

 27  |Guh |97 |F  |20
 28  |Guh |97 |F  |28
 29  |Guh |97 |F  |28
 30  |Guh |97 |F  |23
```

My goal is to have a Query that will produce none duplicate `pack_id`
Something like:

```
|tid |name|age|sex|pack_id
 1   |Joe |57 |M  |77    
 3   |Joe |57 |M  |89
 5   |Joe |57 |M  |94

 6   |Roy |98 |M  |7
 7   |Roy |98 |M  |8
 8   |Roy |98 |M  |9

 12  |Joe |46 |M  |96

 13  |Guh |97 |F  |1

 14  |Kin |68 |F  |33
 18  |Kin |68 |F  |35
 19  |Kin |68 |F  |37

 20  |Pit |43 |F  |77
 21  |Pit |43 |F  |1
 22  |Pit |43 |F  |2

 25  |Joe |71 |M  |75

 26  |Bob |82 |M  |77

 27  |Guh |97 |F  |20
 28  |Guh |97 |F  |28

 30  |Guh |97 |F  |23
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT `tid` ,`name`,`age`,`sex`,`pack_id` FROM `myTable` group by `pack_id` //FAILED
```

Tried this aswell:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`pack_id`) ,`name`,`age`,`sex`,`pack_id` FROM `myTable` group by `pack_id`// RETURNS ONE SINGLE 'name' MANY TIMES
```

Tried

> [MySQL select distinct where in all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856202/mysql-select-distinct-where-in-all)

Tried

> [How can i get all the unique id having more than one id with different address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526264/how-can-i-get-all-the-unique-id-having-more-than-one-id-with-different-address)

Tried many more...

Still can't do it.

Comment: Care to explain what happens with the results of what you've tried?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your desired result set a bit: do you want to return unique combinations of `name` and `pack_id`? If so, what values should be returned for `tid`, `age` and `sex`? It seems that `age` and `sex` are the same for all `name`/`pack_id` pairs, while `tid` has several values.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to `GROUP BY` on two levels: `name` and `pack_id`. For example:

```
SELECT tid,name,age,sex,pack_id FROM yourtable GROUP BY name, pack_id;
```

See [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for more deatils

Comment: Can you please explain the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` part?

Comment: I'm not sure from where you got it, but `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` would be used to only single rows - i.e. `name` and `pack_id` combinations that don't have duplicate rows.

Comment: That was in my answer which I've deleted as incorrect. I misunderstood the question, at first glance I guessed topic starter needs rows with unique `pack_id`.

Comment: i believe this will give an error since there is no aggregate function.

Comment: It is ok to reference columns without aggregate functions in MySQL. One should treat it as a sign that the problem/query hasn't been defined well enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT min(tid), name,age,sex,pack_id 
FROM myTable 
group by name, age, sex, pack_id
```

Comment: WOW!!...Still wonder, I was thinking of `DISTINCT`, Could it have worked?

Comment: no because you have an id that is changing... that's why you need the MIN